# Tournament -> Team -> Player Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm a relative beginner to Rails, but am learning as I go. I'm trying to create a Tournament Entry portal, where a team would enter players for a given tournament. I've done a bit of reading about associations, but am having some trouble wrapping my head around how to apply them in  this instance.

As a basic overview:

- One tournament, has many teams.
- Each team has many players
- Therefore one tournament also has many players (through the teams
  entered)

Here's my code for this, but I'm not sure it's right because I'm unable to get any tournament_ids associated to players.

(tournament.rb)

```
class Tournament < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :teams
  has_many :players, :through => :teams  
end
```

(team.rb)

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tournament
  has_many :players
end
```

(player.rb)

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :team
  has_one :tournament, :through => :team
end
```

Within the Players table there is both team_id & tournament_id fields, however I'm only able to populate the team_id field through association when I try in console.

I'm wondering if there's something amiss with my associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of 'belongs_to', 'has_many', 'has_one' depends on the data model in database of course.

If you have team_id foreign key in `players` table, then you need to define Player class as:

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  has_one :tournament, :through => :team
end
```

In addition, I really believe that Tournament <-> Team should have many-to-many association (if team can participate in many tournaments of course). I would suggest adding model TeamTournament and define final model structure as:

```
class Tournament < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_tournaments
  has_many :teams, :through => :team_tournaments
  has_many :players, :through => :teams
end

class TeamTournament < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :tournament
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_tournaments
  has_many :tournaments, :through => :team_tournaments
  has_many :players
end
```

Comment: Out of interest how would the TeamTournament model be used? I've seen a similar concept in a few different answers & examples around the place, but I'm not able to get my head around the use/concept - perhaps lack of experience.

Answer (score 0):

the Player class should have belongs_to associations with Team and Tournament

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :tournament
end
```

Comment: ```belongs_to :tournament, :through => :team``` won't work

Comment: 'belongs_to' works with foreign_key on current table. Unless 'players' table includes a reference to tournament, tournament can be rather defined as ```has_one :tournament, through: :team```

Answer (score 0):

OK. I assume your question is about your models associations rather than how to set up association for getting `tournament_id` from `player` and so on. So I'll try to hand you some tips about your project and associations could be set up for it.

As I got your portal idea... You want the `tournament` to has many `teams` and the `team` to has many `players`. But then you want to get `tournament_id` from `player`. I believe you don't want to do that because in real life tournament indeed may "has" some players but every single player don't has to belong to some tournament. He can take part in many tournaments. So you don't need to set up association for that. Same thing with tournament and teams. But since team has the player he has to belong to that team. So you need association for that.

Wrapping up my setup for you will be like:

(tournament.rb)

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
end
```

(team.rb)

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
end
```

(player.rb)

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
end
```

And an example about how you can get the `tournament` where certain `team` take part in without the direct association:

```
team = Team.first # just take some team
Tournament.includes(:teams).where(teams: { id: team.id })
```

The same way you can achieve your other goals (get the tournament certain player belongs to and so on). But such cases don't need associations. Associations are needed when the object relates to another conceptually.